# how to shift value from column to column in DataFrame so value shifted equally on 1 day?

Tags: python, pandas

there is a Data Frame with columns `StartQTR, EndQTR, DAte` and `Z`, what is need to be done that for the first pair StartQTR, EndQTR where we have non null Z value, we need to create new column Z1 where we will shift value of Z to Z1 with one day difference.

for example like here

[image]

```
df = pd.read_csv(......)

df['DATE']= pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)

df1 = (df.groupby('START')['HH_F'].shift(freq='1D',periods=1).reset_index()) 
df2 =(pd.merge(df.reset_index(),df1, on=['START','DATE'],          how='left', suffixes=('','1')))
mask = df2.START.duplicated(keep=False)
df2.ix[mask, 'Z1'] = df2.ix[mask, 'Z1'].fillna(0)
print (df2)


----------
START       END            DATE       Z       Z1

21600000    22499000    2012-10-01  0

22500000    23399000    2012-10-01  0   
23400000    24299000    2012-10-01  0   
23400000    24299000    2012-10-01  0   
24300000    25199000    2012-10-01  0   
25200000    26099000    2012-10-01  110412  0


26100000    26999000    2012-10-01  110412  
25200000    26099000    2012-10-02  155886  110412

27900000    28799000    2012-10-02  155886  
28800000    29699000    2012-10-03  160687  

25200000    26099000    2012-10-03  160687  155886
```

Comment: Do you have any code to show us ?

Comment: posted some code that i wrote, but it gives me something not what i need

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "where we will shift value of Z to Z1 with one day difference"? What unit is Z in? Can you give a small example of what your desired input and output would be?

Comment: the input will be like data in example Start, End and Z, the output should be like Z1

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your desired output.

Comment: depending on start and end, everytime when they are the same as the first start and end date with value z(not null) i need to shift z value by day, like z1 , the fiest pair that has value z not null 110412, is   25200000    26099000, so for next time i get pair 25200000    26099000, i need to assign z1 value  110412 (the value of z for previous pair of 25200000    26099000)